# Laravel 5 IoC container unable to resolve contextual bindings when using method injection

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

Inside my Laravel 5 application, I have registered a **contextual binding** for an interface in a service provider like so:

```
$this->app->when('App\Http\Controllers\MyController')
    ->needs('App\Contracts\MyRepositoryInterface')
    ->give('App\Repositories\MyRepostory');
```

Inside the controller `MyController`, I have the `index()` method into which I am trying to inject `MyRepositoryInterface` like so:

```
public function index(App\Contracts\MyRepositoryInterface $repo)
{
    // Stuff
}
```

The problem is, the above doesn't work and gives this error:

> BindingResolutionException in Container.php line 754:
>
> Target [App\Contracts\MyRepositoryInterface] is not instantiable.

However, if I change the **contextual binding** into a normal **binding** like the following, it works:

```
$this->app->bind(
    'App\Contracts\MyRepositoryInterface',
    'App\Repositories\MyRepository'
);
```

Another thing that I have noticed is that the same **contextual binding** works fine for the constructor method for the controller like so:

```
public function __constructor(App\Contracts\MyRepositoryInterface $repo)
{
    // Stuff
}
```

This makes me wonder, is **contextual binding** not supported for method (except constructors) injection? Or is this still a work in progress and will be supported once Laravel 5 comes out?

Or am I doing something terribly wrong?

Any advice would be greatly appreciated, as I have been pulling my hair over this!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This has been finally implemented in Laravel 5 (illuminate/container 5.0), as discussed in the [issue #6177](https://github.com/laravel/framework/issues/6177#issuecomment-73354473).

Comment: it appears this is not the case.

Answer (score 1):

Laravel 5 does not support this as it was not intended to work on methods. A workaround is by extending the ValidatesWhenResolved interface with your own, like:

```
namespace Authentication\Requests\Contracts;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Validation\ValidatesWhenResolved;

interface Validatable extends ValidatesWhenResolved {}
```

And than you can bind to that interface:

```
$this->app->bind('Authentication\Requests\Contracts\Validatable',
'Authentication\Requests\Login');
```

It is not DRY though.

Comment: My answer was based on laravel 5 form requests. But you can extend any interface you like.

Answer (score 0):

L5 is still WIP and this issue has not been resolved yet.

https://github.com/laravel/framework/issues/6177

Comment: Thanks for letting me know - I have posted a comment there. Let's hope they resolve this!